# Delete SQLite row with multiple WHERE arguments in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to delete a record in the database with multiple WHERE arguments.

My database helper class has this method:

```
    public void deleteManualRow(String where){
    try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME_MANUAL, where, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The "where" string which is passed to this method is seen as this through the debugger:

```
eventName='Manual Event 6' AND eventStartTime='2011-07-18T05:40:00.000-0400' AND eventEndTime='2011-07-18T06:40:00.000-0400'
```

How am I supposed to structure this WHERE clause if I want to delete a record with multiple arguments for WHERE?  All of the datatypes are strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this `db.delete(TABLE_NAME_MANUAL,"Column1='5' and column2 like '3'", null);`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the error in my code wasn't because of my SQL syntax.  I was trying to delete a record that actually didn't even exist, hence no result...very dumb mistake on my part.  For discussions sake, I see that in your response you use 'like' instead of '=' for column2.  Why use 'like' instead of '='?  Are '=' and 'like' interchangeable because my code is working when using '=' for column2.

Comment: still two is different you know

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn your sqlite api, next I show from Android flutter example.

From sqlite_api.dart:

```
Future<int> delete(String table, {String where, List<dynamic> whereArgs});
```

So your result code will be:

```
await db.delete(tableName, where: 'place_id = ? and country_id = ?', whereArgs: [place_id, country_id]);
```